# Compile C++ program to run on windows 7 using VS2010 running on windows8

Tags: mfc, compilation, window

I use visual studio 2010 running on Windows 8.1
the program is in C++ and uses MFC library

when I compile it in my computer running windows 8, and then I run it on the destination computer running windows 7, the program stops unexpectedly.

how to compile it specifically for windows 7

Comment: How do you mean "stops unexpectedly"? does it start up and then crash later (what kind of a crash?), or does it not start up at all? What is the (error) message?

Comment: it stops unexpectedly at start-up

Answer (score 0):

Without using a newer SDK there is no special switch to set to compile a program for Windows 7.

Read aboutthe SDK versions and settings for the header files in the `[MSDN][1]`

Even if you use a newer SDK and it is a standard MFC program, than you shouldn't have a problem using it under Windows 7. In 99% of all cases using a newer SDK (with incompatible compiler settings) and run the program on an incompatible (older) OS, the program will not start. In such cases some DLL entry points of new function can't be found.

If you program stops unexectable you should use remote debugging to find the bug. Or use minidumps to do a post mortem analysis. I am sure you have a bug in your program. And that it runs on Windows 8 may be simply luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the values of `WINVER` and/or `_WIN32_WINNT` in your project have been `#define`d as 0x0602 or higher -- see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#macros_for_conditional_declarations) for a list of possible values

Comment: I found out that WINVER is defined as 0x0600. is it ok

Comment: According to the article linked in the answer, a value of 0x0600 means Vista or higher -- make sure that both WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT are `#define`d (preferably in stdafx.h) before you include any .h files

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue of the runtime libraries not being present on the Windows 7 machine.  This can prevent the program from starting with a non-intuitive error message.

In that case, you can install the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package on the Windows 7 machine and see if that helps.  Alternatively you can deploy the application with the runtime library DLL files in the same directory as the .exe.

Comment: The machine has also Visual stdio 2010 installed on it. so the Redistributable Package wouldn't be missing. however, I tried to run the software on another windows 7 machine and it runs without problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a dll project project in my solution, in which target OS version is not defined.

even have the following warning:

```
_WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
```

this might be the problem. After testing it I will confirm the answer